# Sort JSON/JavaScript tuples using command-line tools

Tags: json, bash, sorting, awk

I have a list of JavaScript tuples in a file, one per line, as such:

```
{ x : 12, y : -1.0, as : [ 2, 0, 0 ], str : "xxx", d : 0.041 },
{ x : 27, y : 11.4, as : [ 1, 1, 7 ], str : "yyy", d : 0.235 },
{ x : -4, y :  2.0, as : [ 7, 8, 3 ], str : "zzz", d : 0.002 },
{ x : 44, y :  5.4, as : [ 9, 4, 6 ], str : "kkk", d : 0.176 },
```

I would like to sort them according to the value of a given field (the `d` field in my example), preferably using command-line tools (this is part of a process with many steps).

If it makes any difference, we can assume that all lines have exactly the same length (I can know the start and end index of the `d` value), although I would prefer a solution that doesn't rely on this.

Comment: What you have posted is not valid JSON.  Please either correct the syntax by quoting the keys, or tell us you aren't really using JSON.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can guarantee that all fields are same size, you can use sort command. For example, this sorts by column x value numerically.

```
cat <your file.dat> | sort -n -k 5,7
```

Data you have here as example is not valid JSON but javascript syntax. One way is to wrap the file so it's valid javascript program and run it in node.js command line,

```
var l = [
    { x : 12, y : -1.0, as : [ 2, 0, 0 ], str : "xxx", d : 0.041 },
    { x : 27, y : 11.4, as : [ 1, 1, 7 ], str : "yyy", d : 0.235 },
    ...
]
l.sort(function(o1, o2) { return o1.d < o2.d ? -1 : 1 });
console.log(l);
```

Answer (score 22):

Some time has passed since this question was asked and answered.

These days, a tool-based way would be to use something like [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/):

```
cat data.json | jq 'sort_by(.d)' >> data_sorted.json
```

For more info check the site:

> jq is like sed for JSON data - you can use it to slice and filter and map and transform structured data with the same ease that sed, awk, grep and friends let you play with text.

> -https://stedolan.github.io/jq/

If for some reason you don't like jq, there are many alternatives

- [jsonpipe](https://github.com/dvxhouse/jsonpipe)
- [json](https://github.com/trentm/json)
- [json:select](http://jsonselect.org)
- [json-command](https://github.com/zpoley/json-command)
- [jsawk](https://github.com/micha/jsawk/)
- [jshon](http://kmkeen.com/jshon/)
- [json2](https://github.com/vi/json2)

Comment: The sort_by asserts the input would be an array. If each line of the file is a json object and you want to sort lines by some fields, you could do it as `cat sample.json | jq -s -c 'sort_by(.d) | .[]'`. The option -s would read all lines into an array. Get this idea from http://bigdatums.net/2016/11/29/sorting-json-by-value-with-jq/

Comment: Possibly `cat data.json | jq '.' -S` may do what you want as well

Answer (score 2):

It's a hack, but if each JSON record is one line, and you know that the value for `d` begins after the same number of whitespace-separated tokens on each line, then you can just use

```
sort -g -k 20 < in > out
```

which will compare lines numerically based on the 20th whitespace-separated component.  For increased comfort you could specify a different delimiter with `-t` (perhaps `:`) and adjust the argument to `-k` as necessary, but it's still a hack :)

`sort` is generally carefully optimised for speed, so you're unlikely to find something faster.

Answer (score 1):

If there is a one JSON per row in the input data (as shown in the question), then the @Ashley Coolman's solution does not work, as written [here](https://phpfog.com/sorting-json-by-value-with-jq/):

> Sorting JSON by value with jq can easily be done by using the
> sort_by() function. The main trick with using the sort_by() function
> is that your JSON input must be in an array. There are different ways
> to do this in jq (if your data is not already like this), including
> using the -s or --slurp option. The --slurp option will read all JSON
> input into a JSON array. From this point the data can be sorted by
> value. You can use the .[] syntax to return all elements of the array.

It means that right solution for the data from the question is the following:

```
cat data.json | jq -s -c 'sort_by(.d) | .[]' >> data_sorted.json
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use GNU's `sort` as follows:

```sh
$ sort -t: -k6 -n test.csv
{ x : -4, y :  2.0, as : [ 7, 8, 3 ], str : "zzz", d : 0.002 },
{ x : 12, y : -1.0, as : [ 2, 0, 0 ], str : "xxx", d : 0.041 },
{ x : 44, y :  5.4, as : [ 9, 4, 6 ], str : "kkk", d : 0.176 },
{ x : 27, y : 11.4, as : [ 1, 1, 7 ], str : "yyy", d : 0.235 },
```

The `-k` flag takes the column index. `-t:` is to use the `:` as separators, and `-n` is for numbers.

Of course, this solution as is would not work if you add another field after `d`. If that were the case, you could change the value of `-k` to consider only specific characters, such as `-k6.2,6.6`, but this would assume that the number of digits after the `.` is exactly 3.